# How would I allow a user to move a div up or down using a button or grab handle?

Tags: javascript, html

I am allowing my users in my web app to create quizzes for other users. They can add a question (`div`s) to the `quizList` list by clicking a button. I would like those users to be able to reposition their questions in the order they want so they don't have to delete their question if they don't like the order.

Here is how the questions are dynamically created:

```
function addMultipleChoice() {
    const questionId = Date.now();
    const quizList = document.getElementById('quizList');
    const newQuestion = document.createElement('li');

    const questionHeader = document.createElement('h1');
    questionHeader.classList = 'large-header';
    questionHeader.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 0px');
    questionHeader.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    questionHeader.innerHTML = 'Untitled Question...'

    const questionSubheader = document.createElement('p');
    questionSubheader.classList = 'large-subheader';
    questionSubheader.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    questionSubheader.innerHTML = 'Enter a question description...'

    const answerField = document.createElement('div');

    const answerLabelA = document.createElement('label');
    answerLabelA.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    answerLabelA.innerHTML = 'Answer A'

    const answerInputA = document.createElement('input');
    answerInputA.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    answerInputA.setAttribute('name', questionId)

    const answerLabelB = document.createElement('label');
    answerLabelB.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    answerLabelB.innerHTML = 'Answer B'

    const answerInputB = document.createElement('input');
    answerInputB.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    answerInputB.setAttribute('name', questionId)

    const answerLabelC = document.createElement('label');
    answerLabelC.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    answerLabelC.innerHTML = 'Answer C'

    const answerInputC = document.createElement('input');
    answerInputC.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    answerInputC.setAttribute('name', questionId)

    const answerLabelD = document.createElement('label');
    answerLabelD.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    answerLabelD.innerHTML = 'Answer D'

    const answerInputD = document.createElement('input');
    answerInputD.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    answerInputD.setAttribute('name', questionId)

    quizList.appendChild(newQuestion);

    newQuestion.appendChild(questionHeader);
    newQuestion.appendChild(questionSubheader);
    newQuestion.appendChild(answerField);

    answerField.appendChild(answerInputA)
    answerField.appendChild(answerLabelA);

    answerField.appendChild(answerInputB)
    answerField.appendChild(answerLabelB);

    answerField.appendChild(answerInputC)
    answerField.appendChild(answerLabelC);

    answerField.appendChild(answerInputD)
    answerField.appendChild(answerLabelD);
};
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish in my app. It is a very similar concept to Google Forms:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY62X.jpg

Comment: This will require you to dig into the 'drag&drop' capabilities of HTML/JS. Check [codepen 'drag drop'](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=drag+drop) for examples. Not that hard, but can be a pain in the neck.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Got it. Thank you for the resource! Maybe I'll post an answer here with the best solution.